# AWS RDS Aurora - If a replicated instance becomes overloaded, can other instances also have problems?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am using RDS (Aurora) MySQL on AWS. And I am using 3 readonly reader instances, and I want to use one instance for analysis.
When an analytic instance is overloaded with analytic queries, can other production instances be affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as long as the analysis queries are going directly to the replica's endpoint, no other instances in the cluster would be affected.